# a href click or onclick 2 actions (two functions or more)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a href tag that goes like this :

```
href="download.php?file={$sp->attachment_1}&flag=ds&r_id={$userid}&scpl_id={$sp->sp_id};"
```

that works and downloads the intended file.
the issue is I want it to also call a javascript function.
so when someone click it downloads the pdf file AND calls a javascript function but  I can't get it to work,
I tried using onClick but then it won't download if I put the link there.any suggestions would be greatly appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried returning `True` from the function,

```
onclick="return doAction()"
```

script,

```
function doAction(){
 // do something
 return true
}
```

Comment: I placed return infront of doaction and it worked without adding "return true"

Answer (score 1):

As soon as it redirects to the other page (download.php) you cannot run any javascript on this page.

If you want to do the javascript before, it is possible to say:

```
onclick='do_someting(); window.location="download.php?file=..."'
```

Comment: thank you I didn't think about that one! I actually fixed it differently used onclick="return jsfunction();"

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you can just do this:

```
$("#IDOFYOURLINK").click(function() { 
     yourJavascriptFunction();
});
```

Comment: it wasn't jquery but that you thanks also a good way of doing it